# Finding Exclusive Pairings in Relational Algebra

Tags: relational-theory, relational-algebra

```
classId | studentId
  0          0
  0          1
  0          2
  1          0
  1          1
  1          2
  2          2
```

How do you find the pairs of students (s1, s2) that ONLY have classes with each other? So if student1 has a class, student2 HAS to be in that class to and vice versa.

I know you have to pair them together by classId but how do you eliminate false positives e.g. studentId =2 in this case?